# How to validate the certificate using C#?

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

I am using visual studio 2005 and i wold like to validate the SAML response certificate with the application certificate, here i got a SAML response from identity provider and it sending the SAML response with a certificate, and application have the same certificate seprately, here i need to check whether the SAML response has the SAML certificate or not. Can you please any one help me?
With Thanks,
Gopi G

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample, how to validate signature of the complete SAML authentication response. Assertion signature validation is similar.

```
const string XpathResponseSignatureCertificate = "/samlp:Response/ds:Signature/ds:KeyInfo/ds:X509Data/ds:X509Certificate";

XmlElement xmlResponseSignature =  GetSignatureElement(authenticationResponse);

// Get certificate from IdP metadata document
X509Certificate2 signingCertificate = identityProvider.SigningCertificate;

XmlDocument responseXmlDocument = GetResponseAsXmlDocument(string samlResponse);

XmlNode responseSignatureXmlNode = this.responseXmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(XpathResponseSignatureCertificate, this.namespaceManager);
XmlElement xmlSignature = responseSignatureXmlNode .InnerText.Trim()

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(ResponseXmlDocumen;
signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)xmlSignature);

if (signedXml.CheckSignature(cert, true) == false)
{
    throw new Exception("Not valid signature");
}

bool isReferenceValid = false;
foreach (Reference reference in signedXml.SignedInfo.References)
{
    string refValue = reference.Uri.Substring(1);
    if (refValue  == authenticationResponse.Id)
    {
        isReferenceValid = true;
    }
}

if (isReferenceValid == false)
{
    throw new Exception("Not valid signature reference");
}
```